# How to invention login url as the same facebook?

Tags: php

How to invention login url  as the same facebook ?(PHP)

**+ Example**

```
www.abc.com
```

**+After login**

*user=a1*

```
www.abc.com/a1/index.php
```

*user=a2*

```
www.abc.com/a2/index.php
```

How to invent this in **PHP**?

Comment: it's already been invented, you can use it by having a look at url rewriting. Search google for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PHP, you probably are using Apache with mod_rewrite. An .htaccess rule similar to this will rewrite the username part of the path into a variable accessible to PHP:

```
^/([a-Z0-9]*)/index.php /userhome.php?username=$1
```

This will take a URL like `/foobar/index.php` and map it to the file `userhome.php`, with the variable `$_GET['username']` set to `foobar`.

Comment: Dear Interrobang can you tell me in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Its not as simple as you think..
http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Try looking for something called as *mod_rewrite* with *.htaccess*